# Alias template and confusing syntax

Tags: c++, templates

I copied block on below from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
template<typename T>
void_t<typename T::foo> f();
f<int>(); // error, int does not have a nested type foo
```

I dont understand some of lines of it such us:

`template<typename...>` why type of name not defined in parameter list?

and

`void_t<typename T::foo> f();`  why f() called instead declare?

What does it mean this part? `void_t<typename T::foo>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

is a template alias, `typename...` is for any number of type.
resulting type is `void`.

```
template<typename T> void_t<typename T::foo> f();
```

is a function declaration.
the return type is `void_t<typename T::foo>` so `void` **but**
if `T::foo` is not a valid type, thanks to SFINAE, that overload is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

> why type of name not defined in parameter list?

The ellipsis could be in the template and/or the parameter list. The former is called *variadic template* and the latter is called *variadic function*. So what's the difference?

Variadic template allows you to pass in any number of **types** to the function whereas variadic function allows you to pass in any number of **arguments** into the function. You could use both of them if you want your function to take in any number of types **and** arguments.

> why f() called instead declare?

`f()` is a *function declaration*. I guess it can indeed look confusing. Think of it as `f(void)` instead.